# Undefined commands using hyperref.sty

Tags: hyperref, errors, packages, installing, texlive

To give you a little context. After a happy few months of happily using Emacs/AucTeX I accidentally deleted the hyperref directory (did I mention I'm new to LaTeX and linux?). Since then I've been trying to get it to work again. I've tried both to reinstall this package using tlmgr and downloading the .tds.zip, installing all the files in the directories where they belong (LaTeX is able to find the files) A simple code that generates this error message is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The error message I get is

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
<argument> \ltx@IfUndefined 
                        {pdfdraftmode}{\let \pdf@ifdraftmode \ltx@second...
l.124 }
```

So I understand it is unable to understand the following lines in hyperref.sty:

```
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}[2009/04/10]
\@ifpackagelater{pdftexcmds}{2010/11/04}{}{%
  \ltx@IfUndefined{pdfdraftmode}{%
    \let\pdf@ifdraftmode\ltx@secondoftwo
  }{%
    \ifpdf
      \def\pdf@ifdraftmode{%
        \ifnum\pdfdraftmode=\ltx@one
          \expandafter\ltx@firstoftwo
        \else
          \expandafter\ltx@secondoftwo
        \fi
      }%
    \else
      \let\pdf@ifdraftmode\ltx@secondoftwo
    \fi
  }%
}
```

I've tried to comment these lines out but the problem persists. I also thought the cause would be that the version of pdftexcmds was too old. But this is not so as it's dated 2009/09/23.

If someone can help me figure out I'd be really thankful. If you suggest that I reinstall several packages, instructions on how to do so safely would be appreciated.

Comment: What Linux distribution you use?

Comment: you said you had "deleted the hyperref directory" -- i presume you mean the directory that contained hyperref.sty -- am i right?  what did you do thereafter, to get back to the broken state that you see?  there are 27 files in my  hyperref directory (including hyperref.sty).  some of those will be loaded by hyperref itself: does your log file also contain complaints about missing files?

Comment: Download and install the `oberdiek.tds.zip`.  The author of `hyperref` is the author of many packages, some of which are interrelated, `hyperref` definitely included.  It is available [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib).

Comment: You also might consider doing weekly backups.  I still haven't recovered from my last hard disk crash.  (Actually, I was doing weekly backup, but it seems that Norton doesn't backup .tex .c .h or many other "cult" files unless you specifically add them to the list.)

Comment: I can not reproduce this with an up-to-date TL2013: Update your installation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an out-of-date and somehow broken installation.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: it's off-topic to help people who are confused?  weird ... it's the principle reason i read tex/sx (to find examples of things that people don't understand, with a view toward faq content).  should i sign off this list?

Comment: I installed hyperref v6.83m to get around another problem and then I ran into this problem. oberdiek.tds.zip apparently solved the 'pdfdraftmode' problem (but now I am back with the other problem).